# Retrieving Carrierwave images with S3 signature ultra SLOW

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave + S3 to store my record images in S3.

**The problem is when I retrieve 250 records from a JSON file, loading gets ULTRA slow because it needs to sign individually each version of each image of each record:**

"url":"https://xxxxxx.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product/images/1156/1.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026X-Amz-Credential=xxxxx-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request\u0026X-Amz-Date=20220921T134602Z\u0026X-Amz-Expires=604800\u0026X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\u0026X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxx

**¿How can I retrieve images without needing to sign each one in a fast way?**

**My Carrierwave config file:**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] # for AWS-side bucket access permissions config, see section below
  config.aws_acl    = 'private'

  # Optionally define an asset host for configurations that are fronted by a
  # content host, such as CloudFront.

  # The maximum period for authenticated_urls is only 7 days.
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  # Set custom options such as cache control to leverage browser caching.
  # You can use either a static Hash or a Proc.
  config.aws_attributes = -> { {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  } }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region:            ENV['AWS_REGION'], # Required
    stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? # Optional, avoid hitting S3 actual during tests
  }

  # Optional: Signing of download urls, e.g. for serving private content through
  # CloudFront. Be sure you have the `cloudfront-signer` gem installed and
  # configured:
  # config.aws_signer = -> (unsigned_url, options) do
  #   Aws::CF::Signer.sign_url(unsigned_url, options)
  # end
end
```